# How to implement infinite carousel feature in React with vanilla js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanted to implement an infinite Carousel using react . The problem is that I can't implement the logic that will make the transition from the last image to the first image seem as if they're adjacent to each other . I have watched tutorials and read articles and still can't implement that . Here is my code of the carousel component :

```
import { useState, useRef } from 'react'

const Carousel = () => {
    const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0)
    const [transitionValue, setTransitionValue] = useState(0)
    const carousel = useRef(null)
    const imgsArray = ['/img-1.jpg', '/img-2.jpg', '/img-3.jpg', '/img-4.jpg', '/img-5.jpg']


    const handleIncrement = () => {
        carousel.current.style.transitionDuration = '500ms'
        const updatedCurrent = current === imgsArray.length - 1 ? 0 : current + 1
        console.log('The updated current from the handleIncrement')
        console.log(updatedCurrent)
        setCurrent(updatedCurrent)
        console.log('#########')
        setTransitionValue(carousel.current.clientWidth * updatedCurrent)
    }

    const handleDecrement = () => {
        carousel.current.style.transitionDuration = '500ms'
        const updatedCurrent = current === 0 ? imgsArray.length - 1 : current - 1
        setCurrent(updatedCurrent)
        console.log('The updated current from decrement')
        console.log(updatedCurrent)
        console.log('#######')
        setTransitionValue(carousel.current.clientWidth * updatedCurrent)
        /* The above logic worked by using storing the latest value of current in a variable . This solution was suggested by chatGPT but I didn't understand why so I asked for further explanation for the following inquiry: 
    Since react updates the state values asynchronously, how will the variable get the latest value of the state variable ?
    >> React will create these functions from scratch during every re-render, so the updatedCurrent variable will have access to the latest value of the current variable . */
    }


    return (
        <>
            <ul
                ref={carousel}
                style={{ transform: `translateX(-${transitionValue}px)` }}
            >
                {imgsArray.map((imgSource) => (
                    <li key={imgSource}>
                        <img
                            src={imgSource}
                            alt={imgSource.slice(0, -4)}
                        />
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
            <button
                className='left-arrow'
                onClick={handleDecrement}
            >
                &#8249;
            </button>
            <button
                className='right-arrow'
                onClick={handleIncrement}
            >
                &#8250;
            </button>
        </>
    )
}
export default Carousel
```

Link to the full repo on github:
https://github.com/Mohammed-Lashein/react-infinite-carousel